# Select all values matching several values in second column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table like this:

```
    ID       VALUE

--------------------
     A   |    abc       <---  
--------------------
     A   |    def       <---
--------------------
     A   |    ghi       <---
--------------------
     B   |    abc       x
--------------------
     C   |    abc       x
--------------------
     C   |    def       x
--------------------
     C   |    xyz       x
--------------------       
     D   |    abc       <---
--------------------
     D   |    def       <---
--------------------
     D   |    ghi       <---
```

I'd like to select all IDs where an ID is matching all the values (abc, def **AND** ghi)

Result should be

```
A 
D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from t
where value in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
group by id
having count(*) = 3;
```

If you can have duplicate `id`/`value` pairs, use `count(distinct id)` instead of `count(*)`.

If you have only three values in the table, you can dispense with the `where`.  Or, if you want all values in the table:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct value) from t)
```